# How to select MAX from AVG?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I'm practicing for my SQL exam and I can't figure out the following question:

"Of the average amount paid per customer, show the highest amount."

So to retrieve the average amount paid, I would do the following:

```
SELECT AVG(Amount) AS 'Average amount paid'
FROM Payment;
```

Then I would like to retrieve the highest average amount out of this list of averages. I thought the following would do the trick:

```
SELECT MAX(AVG(Amount)) AS 'Highest average amount paid'
FROM Payment;
```

This doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I would like some help with this. What is the correct way to approach this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which dbms is used?

Comment: Apologies, should've made that clear. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You already have some answers but if you read the requirement carefully you should realize even your first sql query is wrong. Right?

Comment: Then Gordon's answer won't work. For some odd reason SQL Server only supports FETCH FIRST in combination with OFFSET. Use SELECT TOP instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can order the records and use `TOP 1` to keep only the record that has the highest amount:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Customer_id, AVG(Amount) AS [Average amount paid]
FROM Payment
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY [Average amount paid] DESC;
```

Note: for this query to make sense, you need a `GROUP BY` clause. Without it, it would just return one record, with the average of payments within the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(src.cust_avg) AS "Highest average amount paid"
FROM (
  SELECT cust_id, AVG(Amount) AS cust_avg
  FROM Payment
  GROUP BY cust_id -- Get averages per customer
) src 
;
```

To get the "per customer" averages first, you need include something like `GROUP BY cust_id`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ac1fd7/1)

Comment: That last line was just to explain the `GROUP BY` I added to the original poster's initial query.  The wording is confusing -- you don't need to add a second `GROUP BY`.  I'll clarify, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use `order by`:

```
select customer, avg(amount)
from payment
group by customer
order by avg(amount) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

The `fetch first` (although standard) is not supported by all databases, so you should use the version appropriate for your database.

In SQL Server, you would use either `select top (1)` or `offset 0 fetch first 1 row only` (the `offset` is not optional, alas).

There are also databases where `avg()` on an integer returns an integer.  If `amount` is an integer *and* your database does this, then use `avg(amount * 1.0)`.